# Why are the rules not working for input file? (beginner)

Tags: jquery

I want to upload 5 files from the user. I want the file-size to be less than 4MB, file-type to be jpg|jpeg|png and the user must upload 5 files compulsorily. I want to add these rules in my jquery validate. I have done the following:

```
     $.validator.addMethod("filesize", function (value, element, param) {

    return this.optional(element) || (element.files[0].size <= param)
  });

  $.validator.addMethod("numfile", function(value, element){

    var numFiles = $("input:file", this)[0].files.length;

    if(numFiles != 5){
      return false;
    } 
    return true;
  }, 'Number of images should be equal to 5');
```

I have these rules for the above scenarios. However, they dont seem to work.